# Semantics of pre- and postfix "++" operator in Java

Tags: java, post-increment, pre-increment

I wondering to know why this snippet of code give output `112`
How this last digit `2` was creating?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 0;
    System.out.print(++i);
    System.out.print(i++);
    System.out.print(i);
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with iteration.

Comment: `++i` means increment and read `i`, `i++` means read and increment `i`, and `i` means read `i`.

Comment: As a general rule; never do this, it leads to unreadable code, increment and use a value seperately

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your snippet it's translated as

```
int i = 0;
i = i + 1; // 1
System.out.print(i); // 1
System.out.print(i); // 1
i = i + 1; // 2
System.out.print(i); // 2
```

That's why the final result it's a 2.

`++i` it's incrementing the variable before being called by the print method and `i++` it's incrementing the variable after the method execution.

Answer (score 3):

`i++` is the post-increment operator, which has expression value the old value of `i`, but a side-effect of incrementing `i`. The value is `1`, but it leaves `i` changed to `2`.

Answer (score 2):

When we use post or pre increment operator it increases the value.

Post increment operator (`i++`) assigns the value first, then increments it. Pre increment operator (`++i`) increments first then assigns the value.
They both behave like this :

```
int i=0;
i=i++;
System.out.println(i); //1
i=++i;
System.ou.println(i); //1
```

Answer (score 2):

When this code runs:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 0;                //i=0;
    System.out.print(++i);    // increments i to i=1, and prints i
    System.out.print(i++);    // prints i and then increments it to i=2
    System.out.print(i);      // prints i, i.e. 2
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i is initially 0, then it is pre-incremented and printed so you have the first 1, then it is printed again and you have the second 1, then post-incremented, then printed for the last time and you have the 2

Answer (score 1):

You are applying two increments on `i`. The initial value was 0 so after two increments (`++i` and `i++` )it will become 2.

Both `i++` and `++i` are incrementing the value of `i` by one.

They are similar to

```
i = i+1;
```

but the `++i` one increments the value of `i` then uses it, so `0` becomes `1` and printed out, while the `i++` first uses the value and then increments the value of `i`, so the printed value is `1` and then it becomes `2` hence the last digit(the final value of  `i`) is 2.

Answer (score 1):

Simply;

In post increment, the increment is done after the variable is read.

In pre increment, the variable value is incremented first, then used in the expression.